# HttpContext.Current.User is null in OnConnected with Asp.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I created two projects from templates.

The first contains Membership and MVC4. And the second uses MVC5 and Asp.Net Identity.

Then I added signalR to both projects using same code.

In Membership project I can access HttpContext.User both in controllers and SignalR connection class(OnConnected method). But in Identity project I have proper value of HttpContext.User only in controllers. In OnConnected method HttpContext.User returns null.

Code of signalR is same in both projects:

1) *SynchronizationConnection.cs*

```
public class SynchronizationConnection : PersistentConnection
{
    public SynchronizationConnection()
    { 
    }
    protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return base.OnReceived(request, connectionId, data);
    }

    protected override Task OnConnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        Debugger.Break(); //HttpContext.Current.User == null
        return base.OnConnected(request, connectionId);
    }

    protected override Task OnDisconnected(IRequest request, string connectionId)
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        return base.OnDisconnected(request, connectionId);
    }
}
```

2) *Startup.cs*

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

3) *Startup.Auth.cs*

```
public partial class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR<Services.Realtime.SynchronizationConnection>("/test");
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    }
}
```

4) *Client javascript*

```
var connection = $.connection('/test');
connection.logging = true;
console.log('Receiving connection');
connection.received(function (data) {
    console.log('received');  
});

connection.disconnected(function () {
    console.log('disconnected');
});

connection.error(function (data) {
    console.log('error');
});

connection.start().done(function () {
    console.log('Connection started');
});
```

I've seen questions about null User.Identity.Name because of missing [Authorize] attribute. In my case I cannot access even User.Identity. Also I have [Authorize] attribute on my action, that contains client javascript.

Comment: How did you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the `OnConnected` method, you can use:

```
request.User
```

That will carry the `IPrincipal` that was in the `HttpContext.Current.User` at the time of connection, and it is the one you should mind.

If you need to alter that `IPrincipal` (like removing the default one generated by Forms authentication and set your own), I recommend you to use an `IHttpModule`. All the transports in SignalR at least start as an HTTP (even WebSockets), so all transports are going to hit the module at least during connection.

Cheers.

Comment: I've tried request.User at first. It is null too. I am sorry for inaccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: request.User was null in the PersistentConnection's OnConnected() method. Changing the order in which I initialized SignalR and my authentication provider fixed it. I changed it so that my SignalR endpoints were mapped *after* my authentication was configured:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(999, 0, 0, 0),
    SlidingExpiration = true
});

GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("MyDatabase", new SqlServerStorageOptions() { PrepareSchemaIfNecessary = false });

app.MapSignalR<MyConnection>("/MyConnection");
```